# In wordpress, why I should register and enqueue js scripts with wp_register_script() and wp_enqueue_script()?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Why not to add the script that I need simply in the HTML content?

Comment: Refer to this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque)

Answer (score 2):

Here are few reasons for **WHY!**

- First of all, it makes you AWESOME among your friends
- It helps define the dependencies of the script you are using, like won't need to enqueue other scripts like jquery, jquery-ui, thickbox or any other scripts if you have already registered one.
- It makes your code more semantic, and your code will make more sense.
- Your theme or plugin will have less chance of conflicting with other's (like double loading jquery files, fancybox files and so on)
- You will have more control where you want the js to embed on pages with simple conditional tags like

> if(is_page() || is_single()){ wp_enqueue_script(......); }

Answer (score 0):

Because plugins need a way to add scripts too.